# Prisma Unsupported("point") MySql Approach

Tags: mysql, orm, prisma

So I have my **location** column using [Point](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-type-overview.html) data type, I'm using Apollo Server and Prisma, and when I use "npx prisma db pull" generates this data type because is not currently supported on Prisma [(generated script)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtVkT.jpg)

so I say "Ok, I'm using string and I manage how to insert this data type" so I changed to [this script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeoUn.jpg), surprise! didn't work [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Biimg.jpg), try to find any approach to handling MySql Point data type in Prisma but no info at soever, I really appreciate any ideas

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert it to `String` and use it as it [isn't supported yet](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5683). You need to leave it as unsupported and you can only add data via [raw queries](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access).

For now, only adding data is supported. You cannot query for it using `PrismaClient`.

Answer (score 0):

We can query data using Prisma Client, via raw queries as `SELECT id, ST_AsText(geom) as geom from training_data` where geom has dataType geometry for using Unsupported("geometry").